# Is there a convenient, maintainable way to get the actual arguments list from within function?

Tags: r, introspection

Suppose that I'm writing a function `foo` with signature

```
foo <- function (bar, baz, frobozz, quux = TRUE, frotz = 42) {
           # etc.
       }
```

If, within this function's body, I wanted to get a **named list** of the actual arguments that the function received at run time, I could define

```
actual_args <- list(bar = bar, baz = baz, frobozz = frobozz, quux = quux,
                    frotz = frotz)
```

...but this assignment is difficult to maintain, since it needs to be modified every time an argument gets added, removed, or renamed.  (Not to mention that it is also tedious to write.)

Is there a way to initialize `actual_args` that would remain invariant with respect to future changes in the function's signature?

Comment: You should use the actual case, and your efforts at debugging, rather than complaining about answers that were accurate for this simple case. Soe things will not be possible. For instance there is an oft-repeated request to get the names of values passed by lapply and sapply ... they simply aren't available.

Comment: @42: that's completely unfair.  I did not "complain"; I simply stated the facts, in case the additional information lead to a revised or new answer.  I will accept the best answer to my question, *as I posted it*, in due course, even if it does not work for the problem I am actually dealing with.  I had no way to know that the simple case I posted would differ from the actual case the way it turns out to.  The question is interesting to me only in the general sense that I posted it.  If the solution to this general case does not work for my current problem, so be it.

Comment: Completely unfair? You posted an over-simplified question and then said the solution fails for your actual use case. The recommended way of getting clarification for an answer that is not satisfactory is to post an edit to your question rather than posting multipart comments.

Comment: @42-: yes, unfair: how was I supposed to know that the simplified case I posted would differ from the actual case in the way it does?

Comment: I didn't say you should have know that. I am _still_ saying you should instead have editted your question.

Comment: @42-: 1. The word "complain" entails a value judgement. 2. If I had followed the course of action you insist I should have, I would have, almost certainly, gotten answers valid only for that exceedingly rare and narrow use case; *I am not interested in such answers*; I am much happier with the answers I did get, including the one I accepted.

Comment: I don't blindly accept that  you would have "almost surely" gotten an answer to the actual use case, because I still suspect that it was analogous to the cases involving `lapply` or `sapply` that I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls()` in a function to get a list of all the variables defined. If you call that right after the function starts, you'll get a list of all the parameters. You can then use `mget()` to put those values in a list. For example

```
foo<-function(a,b,c) {
    mget(ls())
}
```

This will work with your `do.call`/`mapply` scenario

```
df <- data.frame(
    a=1:3,
    b=letters[1:3],
    c = runif(3))

do.call("mapply", c(foo, df))
#   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
# a 1         2         3        
# b factor,1  factor,1  factor,1 
# c 0.7845643 0.0297852 0.3611791
```

Answer (score 3):

See `?match.call`

```
foo <- function(a, b, c, d, ...)
match.call()

foo(1, 2, 3, bar, e=baz())
# foo(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = bar, e = baz())
```

This is a call object, whose first argument is the name of the function called (`foo` in this case). The other arguments are the *unevaluated* arguments to `foo`.

```
foo(1, 2, 3, bar, e=baz())[[1]]
# foo

foo(1, 2, 3, bar, e=baz())[[2]]
# 1

# the name of a variable
foo(1, 2, 3, bar, e=baz())[[5]]
# bar

# a function call
foo(1, 2, 3, bar, e=baz())[[6]]
# baz()
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works for the simple example I gave in my question, but, to my surprise, it fails for the more complex problem I'm working with.  The actual function I'm working with is one that gets called via `mapply`, like this: `do.call(mapply, c(foo, df))`, where `df` is a `data.frame` whose columns are named in a way consistent with the names of `foo`'s arguments...  Under these conditions, the value returned by `match.call` has elements like `dots[[1L]][[1L]]`, etc.  ...

Comment: (cont'd.) If I stop execution right after the assignment to `actual_args` (using `browser()`), and try to evaluate `dots`, I get `Error: object 'dots' not found`, so I have no idea of what this `dots` is.  (The documentation for `match.call` says nothing about it.)

Comment: In the browser you could try this: `dts <- list(...)` to force evaluation of the ellipsis value at that point.